# Liquibase error: No inverse to liquibase.change.core.RawSQLChange created

Tags: mysql, maven, liquibase, devops

i created the following changeset

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset machado:1 runOnChange:true failOnError:true endDelimiter:/
CREATE FUNCTION get_max_age() RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE MAX_AGE INT DEFAULT 0;
select max(age) into MAX_AGE   from employees;
RETURN MAX_AGE;
END/

--rollback DROP FUNCTION get_max_age
```

i tried execute rollback with "liquibase:rollback --Dliquibase.rollbackCount=1" to erase this function but i catch this error:

> "Error setting up or running Liquibase:
>   liquibase.exception.RollbackImpossibleException: No inverse to
>   liquibase.change.core.RawSQLChange created"

What better way to rollback this function created with liquibase?

Comment: Put the error into a quote block so it would stand out.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is the explicit the rollback request by deleting the function in the changeset.

Liquibase cannot infer the rollback for sql requests.